# laravel php update all row in database if deadline is reached?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

How to update all records in a column every minute?

I have this example:

I borrowed a book at(9/1/2016) and the deadline of my borrowed book is on (9/2/2016), when the deadline has passed and i still didn't return the book after 1 week ill have a total penalty of 7 points. 1 point per day for not returning a book.

For example today is 9/4/2016 my total penalty points is 2 points

```
borroweddate| deadline | penalty
------      | ------   |---------
9/1/2016    | 9/2/2016 |    2
```

It's hard to explain sorry please help me.

Comment: You might want to do the check and update everyday say after 12am, not every minute

Comment: thats actually my plan, but for testing purpose ill use every minute :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) to run your command/script. If you want to schedule your command minutely you can use:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/your/scriptcommand >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

For laravel apps you can use [laravel task scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling), but you still need cron to run your command. You can use laravel scheduling minutely with this:

```
    $schedule->call(function () {
        DB::table('your_table')->update(['table_field' => 'some_value' ]);
    })->everyMinute();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @Folio, but i dont know how to use cron..i installed it and created my function in app/console/kernel.php 
this is my command:
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            Tbl_users::where('student_id', "2013-0207-IC")->update(['penalty' => 5 ]);
        })->everyMinute();
    }

and now im stuck XD

Comment: Do you use linux/unix as your development environment? as far as i know cron is only available there. If you use windows maybe you can try windows task scheduler.

Comment: nvm that :D, i happen to make it work now..yes i use windows but i am using c9.io in my browser..now my problem is that the command only execute once and it only executes after i entered this command: 'php artisan schedule:run' in my terminal after that it needs to be entered again in order to change the values inside the database

Comment: looks like c9.io do not support cron by default (https://community.c9.io/t/how-to-enable-run-cron/2250) . Have you tried using laravel homestead?

Comment: oh ill be damned, sorry but im new in laravel i have no background in laravel homestead